# mysql probleme, "else" is not valid at this position, expecting : END

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL but as long as I'm a beginner I need some help do understand and solve this problem

```
delimiter ./
create procedure getMesuresBetweenDates (in debut timestamp , in fin timestamp , in nomWaspmote varchar(16) , in nomSensor varchar(16) , out resultat int)
begin
declare compte int;
set compte = NULL;
If debut>=fin then set resultat = -2; end if;
else If Not Exists sensorParser then set resultat = -1 ; end if;
else select @compte=count(*) value, timestamp from sensorParser where id_wasp = nomWaspmote and sensor = nomSensor and timestamp >= debut and timestamp <= fin;
if @compte=0 then set resultat = 0; end if;
else set resultat = @compte;
end ./
```

It's the first else which doesn't work, when I overfly it, it tells "else' is not valid at this position, expecting : END

I'm French so I hope my english isn't too bad

Here is the new code, thanks to Bart :

```
delimiter ./
create procedure getMesuresBetweenDates (in debut timestamp , in fin timestamp , in nomWaspmote varchar(16) , in nomSensor varchar(16) , out resultat int)
begin
declare compte int;
set compte = NULL;
If debut>=fin then 
    set resultat = -2;
else If Not Exists (select * from sensorParser) then 
    set resultat = -1 ;
else select @compte=count(*) value, timestamp from sensorParser where id_wasp = nomWaspmote and sensor = nomSensor and timestamp >= debut and timestamp <= fin;
if @compte=0 then
    set resultat = 0;
else set resultat = @compte;
end if;
end ./
```

it worked in a way but now I have another problem with end : it tells me that the statement is incomplete, it's expecting an IF but I don't know where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't end all `if` blocks with an `end if`, only after the `else`:

```
If debut>=fin then 
     set resultat = -2; 
     -- don't put "end if" here
else 
     -- do something else
end if;
```

as a general note, when creating complex structures like this, make sure you intend correctly, to keep it readable.

If you want to do more `else`s in one `if`, you have to use `elseif`:

```
If debut>=fin then 
     set resultat = -2; 
     -- don't put "end if" here
elseif fin>=debut then
     -- do something else
else
     -- do yet something else
end if;
```

If you do it in the way you have written, you have to close all `if`s with an `end if`:

```
if debut >= fin then
    -- do something
else if fin >= debut then        -- you start a new "if" here!
                                 -- notice the space between else and if
    -- do the else
     end if                      -- end the second if
end if                           -- end the first if
```

See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter ./
create procedure getMesuresBetweenDates (in debut timestamp , in fin timestamp , in nomWaspmote varchar(16) , in nomSensor varchar(16) , out resultat int)
begin
declare compte int;
set compte = NULL;
If debut>=fin then 
    set resultat = -2; 
else If Not Exists sensorParser then 
    set resultat = -1 ; 
else 
     select @compte=count(*) value, timestamp from sensorParser where id_wasp = nomWaspmote and sensor = nomSensor and timestamp >= debut and timestamp <= fin;
end if;
if @compte=0 then 
   set resultat = 0; 
else set resultat = @compte;
end if;
end ./
```

end if; too many and set in wrong places